# Work WiFi NSFW mistake

Tags: privacy

Here’s my stupid story of the day...

At work, on the work WiFi. (Which is rare for me and I always turn off my WiFi at work...except today..of course.)
I wanted to send a url from a craigslist post to a friend using iMessage. I pressed “paste” a url popped up and I hit send. Just as I realized it was a link to a NSFW site that I had previously messaged and was meant for someone else. The iPhones messanger preview added the picture in the text thread too.
 Luckily it was a good buddy and we got a good laugh out of the mistake. But I’m worried that by pasting the site from clipboard, and sending it while on work WiFi that I am going to get popped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my employer see what I do on the internet when I am connected to the company network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142803/can-my-employer-see-what-i-do-on-the-internet-when-i-am-connected-to-the-company) and [Can an employer see what I'm doing on my iPhone whilst logged onto wifi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90162/can-an-employer-see-what-im-doing-on-my-iphone-whilst-logged-onto-wifi).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is a **yes-no**.

iMessage is implemented in an **end-to-end encryption** structure. This means that the messages are only decrypted by your device (or iCloud account).

You can read more about iMessage encryption [here](https://techcrunch.com/2014/02/27/apple-explains-exactly-how-secure-imessage-really-is/).

However, there is no way to be sure, unless you are aware of how WiFi usage is monitored by your employer. There is a high chance that they can see all what you do. This is because they own the actual network.